# Error: Actions must be plain objects. But i'm not using async calls

Tags: reactjs, redux

SwitchActions.js

```
 import HANDLE_SWITCH from './SwitchActionTypes'

 export const toggleSwitchButton = event =>     ({
    type: HANDLE_SWITCH.TOGGLE_SWITCH,
    payload: event
})
```

SwitchTypes.js

```
const HANDLE_SWITCH = {
    TOGGLE_SWITCH: 'TOGGLE_SWITCH'
}

export default (HANDLE_SWITCH)
```

SwitchReducer

```
import HANDLE_SWITCH from './SwitchActionTypes'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    A: true,
    B: false,
    C: false,
    D: false,
    E: false,
}

const switchReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case HANDLE_SWITCH.TOGGLE_SWITCH:
            return {
                ...state, 
                [action.name]: action.event
                }
        default: 
            return {...state}
    }
}

export default switchReducer
```

SwitchComponent

```
import React from 'react';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleSwitchButton } from '../../Redux/Switch/SwitchActions'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        color: 'white',
    },
}));

function SwitchLabels({ switchState,  toggleSwitch }) {

    const classes = useStyles()

    return (
        <FormGroup>
            <FormControlLabel
                control={
                    <Switch checked={switchState.A} onChange={toggleSwitch('A')} value="A" />
                }
                label="Data Plot"
                classes={{
                    root: classes.root
                }}
            />
            <FormControlLabel
                control={
                    <Switch
                        checked={switchState.B}
                        onChange={toggleSwitch('B')}
                        value="B"
                        color="secondary"
                    />
                }
                classes={{
                    root: classes.root
                }}
                label="Linear Regression"
            />
        </FormGroup>
    );
}

const mapDispatch = dispatch => {
    return {
        toggleSwitch: (event) => dispatch(toggleSwitchButton)(event)
    }
}

const mapState = (state) => {
    const switchState = state
    return {switchState}
}

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(SwitchLabels)
```

I'm not even using async calls.
'mapState' works properly, but whenever i click that button it returns this error.
I'm using the Switch component from Material-ui https://material-ui.com/components/switches/#switches-with-formcontrollabel
Somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dispatch syntax is wrong:

```js
(event) => dispatch(toggleSwitchButton)(event)
```

That is passing the `toggleSwitchButton` action creator to `dispatch`, instead of *calling* `toggleSwitchButton()` and passing the resulting action object to `dispatch`.

It should be:

```js
(event) => dispatch(toggleSwitchButton(event))
```

However, we strongly recommend using [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) instead:

```js
const mapDispatch = {toggleSwitch: toggleSwitchButton};
```

In addition, your usage inside the component is wrong:

```js
onChange={toggleSwitch('B')}
```

This will call `toggleSwitch()` and dispatch an action while the component is in the middle of rendering.  Instead, [you need to pass a reference to a function that will pass the right parameter when clicked](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-a-parameter-to-an-event-handler-or-callback):

```js
onChange={ () => toggleSwitch('B')}
```